# How to pass paramters to mouse events (if possible) in Java?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jlabel, mouse-listeners

Okay, so this question is probably way too basic, but I've been Googling around and haven't been able to dig up a solution (or even a workaround).  My apologies in advance if some of you don't like this.

I'm creating a GUI app with a few buttons, so of course for that we need a mouse event (for when one of the buttons is clicked).  So for example:

```
public class myProject extends JFrame implements MouseListener {
    public int x = 4;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Jframe app = new JFrame();
        app.setTitle // and all that jazz...        
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setText("Old text");
        app.add(label);

        // Then later on...
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            app.setTitle("New Title");
            label.setText("New text");
            System.out.println(x);
            // "app" and "label" throw errors, cannot find symbol
            // But x is fine...?
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried making the app elements public/private instance variables, but that didn't seem to change anything.  I even tried creating a sort of intermediary class to help, one that would copy references to the interactors as instance variables, and having the mouse event call methods that use those references (the second attempt was very close to the code above; but by trying to refer to set public variables from the main method gave me more errors (about how we can't call non-static objects from a static method).

So, bottom line, battling this beastly bug has been a "wild goose chase" so far, so I'd appreciate any tips/tricks/workarounds you may know of.  Thanks.  : )

Comment: it's a little unclear for me, but why do you want to store a variable in a static var? it's not safe! simply just pass the mouse event instance to the target method, would you explain more?! share the stack trace?

Comment: Your mouseclick method is declared inside main method, it should not work.

Comment: *"a few buttons, so of course for that we need a mouse event"*  Of course you don't.  Add an `ActionListener` to buttons in order to respond to both mouse input ***and the keyboard.***

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try changing your code to something like this

```
Jframe app;
JLabel label;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
           new myProject();
        }

    public myProject()
    {
          app = new JFrame();
          app.setTitle // and all that jazz...        
          label = new JLabel();
          label.setText("Old text");
          app.add(label);
    }
      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
          app.setTitle("New Title");
          label.setText("New text");
          System.out.println(x);
      }
```

Comment: This made it much easier to work with the different elemnts of my program (as the whole "static" thing really seems to add an extra layer of complexity to the program; it's an area I will need to research in further detail to understand why it does what it does).  As far as the "method within a method" thing, that was a typo on my part; that was a summary of my source code written in Notepad; sorry about that.  Anyway by having the main method call a non-static object helps.  Thanks also to Andrew for the whole ActionListener.  I was unaware there was a single listener for both mouse and keys.

Answer (score 0):

May you show the full code of the class. Now it looks like method in method. If it is an inner class, you can't get the app, label and x value if they are not final.